# MySQL - how do I reduce this table to one with total costs?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, jdbc, aggregate-functions

Say I have a table (TreatmentsPerformed) containing all the treatments performed by a practitioner, with the appointmentID of the appointment that they were performed in and the cost of the particular treatments. See here example here:

```
TreatmentsPerformed 
appointmentID   treatment   treatmentCost
3               tmnt1       30
3               tmnt2       100
3               tmnt3       200
4               tmnt2       100
5               tmnt1       30
5               tmnt3       200
6               tmnt2       100
6               tmnt3       200
```

Is it possible to select a result set that has the total cost for each of the appointments with one query? How would I go about this?
The desired result for the above example is this:

```
AppointmentCost

appointmentID   totalCost
 3              330
 4              100
 5              230
 6              300
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this

`SELECT appointmentId, SUM(treatmentCost) as totalCost FROM table GROUP BY appointmentID;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Group By` and `Order By` clauses to achieve this.

**`Group By:`**

> `SQL` - `Group By`. ... The `SQL GROUP BY` clause is used in collaboration
>   with the `SELECT` statement to arrange identical data into groups. The
>   `GROUP BY` clause follows the `WHERE` clause in a `SELECT` statement and
>   precedes the `ORDER BY` clause.

**`Order By:`**

> The `SQL ORDER BY` clause is used to sort the data in ascending or
>   descending order, based on one or more columns. Some database sorts
>   query results in ascending order by default.

So your query will look like:

```
SELECT 
    appointmentId, SUM(treatmentCost) AS totalCost
FROM 
    table_name 
GROUP BY 
    appointmentID
ORDER BY
    appointmentID;
```